# ReleaseSemaphore returns error 6 (Invalid Handle)

Tags: c++, winapi, semaphore

I'm trying to use two threads to run a server and a client.
I use a **semaphore** to block the client thread from doing too much before the server has been set up (`ListenSocket`, etc.).

When The server gets far enough, I use `ReleaseSemaphore()` but it returns an `Invalid Handle` error.
I've read that there are many possible issues which can be the source of this error.

The exact line is `if (ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore, 1, NULL)){}` which can be found about 55% of the way into the `Server.cpp` file

**Header.h**:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

unsigned int __stdcall servermain(void*);

unsigned int __stdcall clientmain(void*);

static HANDLE semaphore;
```

**Source.cpp**:

```
#include "Header.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE serverHandle, clientHandle;

    semaphore = CreateSemaphore(
        NULL,
        0,  //initial count
        1,  //max count
        NULL);

    if (semaphore == NULL){
        printf("CreateSemaphore error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }


    /*call to the methods in the Client and Server files*/
    serverHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &servermain, 0, 0, 0);
    clientHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &clientmain, 0, 0, 0);

    WaitForSingleObject(serverHandle, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(clientHandle, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(serverHandle);
    CloseHandle(clientHandle);
    CloseHandle(semaphore);

    return 0;
}
```

**Server.cpp**:

```
#include "Header.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

unsigned int __stdcall servermain(void* data)
{
    printf("SERVER STARTED. Thread: %i\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo
        *result = NULL,
        hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); //initiates the use of the Winsock DLL
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////
    // Creating a Socket for the Server //
    //////////////////////////////////////

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    //////////////////////
    // Binding a Socket //
    //////////////////////

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    char answer = 'y'; // char answer[8]; // char *answer = "";
    do{
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());

        printf("Would you like to wait for client?(Y/N)\t");

        answer = getchar(); // fgets(answer, 1, stdin);
        printf("%c\n", answer);
    } while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n'); // double quotes "" are for c-strings. single quotes '' are for chars.

    if (answer == 'n'){
        return 1;
    }
    else printf("%i Server:\tListening for a client...\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    printf("Semaphore value: %i\n", semaphore);

    //Now that the server is running, signal the semaphore to allow client to connect.
    if (ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore, 1, NULL)) //ReleaseSemaphore() returns a bool value
    {
        printf("%i Server: Semaphore Released\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Server Release Semaphore error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        printf("Server Semaphore value: %i\n", semaphore);
        return 1;
    }


    ///////////////////////////
    // Listening on a Socket //
    ///////////////////////////

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    // Accepting a Connection //
    ////////////////////////////

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket); // This will need to be changed if multiple clients shall be allowed

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Receiving and Sending Data on the Server //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());

            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket); //why close a socket if something doesn't send correctly?
                WSACleanup();
                return 1; //kills main()
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup(); //function terminates use of the Winsock 2 DLL (Ws2_32.dll)
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the send half of the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("%i Server:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    _endthreadex(0); //end thread within the thread.
    return 0;
}
```

**Client.cpp**:

```
#include "Header.h"

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

unsigned int __stdcall clientmain(void* data)
{
    printf("CLIENT STARTED. Thread: %i\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
    /*if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }*/


    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("%i Client:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Client winsock initialized\n");

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    /*iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }*/


    printf("%i Client: before semaphore\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    //Wait for Server to be up and running

    bool cont = TRUE;
    while (cont)
    {
        DWORD returnval = WaitForSingleObject(semaphore, 0L); // 0 vs 0L ?

        //printf("Semaphore value: %i\n", semaphore);

        switch (returnval)
        {
            // The semaphore object was signaled.
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                printf("Thread %d: wait succeeded\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

                break;

                // The semaphore was nonsignaled, so a time-out occurred.
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                printf("Thread %d: wait timed out\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("%i Client: after semaphore\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("%i Client:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("%i Client:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("%i Client:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("%i Client:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {
        printf("%i Client:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    printf("%i Client:\t", GetCurrentThreadId());
    printf("\nReturn to close.\n");
    getchar(); //allow user to do see screen before shutting down

    _endthreadex(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You declare `semaphore` as a `static HANDLE` in `header.h`.  That means that every source module that includes `"header.h"` will have its own copy of that variable.  Thus, the `semaphore` in main.cpp that holds the Windows semaphore handle is a different variable than the `semaphore` referenced in `server.cpp`.

Remove the `static` from the declaration in `header.h`, replace it with `extern`, and add a definition for it in `main.cpp`.

Comment: In the latest versions of C++, you could just replace "static" with "inline". No definition in a .cpp file required.