# c++ ReleaseSemaphore returns invalid handle error

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, semaphore

When I try to release a semaphore I get this error 6, invalid handle. My code looks something like this:

```
result = WaitForSingleObject(sem, INFINITE);
switch (result) {
  case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    //Right
    ...
  case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    //error
    ...
}

...

if (ReleaseSemaphore(sem, 1, &previous_val) == 0) {
  //error
}
...
```

There are several threads running through this code. I don't know where the problem may be.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674760/releasesemaphore-returns-error-6-invalid-handle) but it didn't help me with my issue.

Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define PERROR(a) \
{             \
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;                                         \
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |           \
               FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |                  \
               FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL,          \
               GetLastError(),                               \
               MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),    \
               (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,0,NULL );                  \
    fprintf(stderr,"%s:(%d)%s\n",a,GetLastError(),lpMsgBuf); \
    LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );                                   \
}
HANDLE sem;
LPCTSTR  sem_id;
DWORD WINAPI threadFunction(LPVOID par);

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD thread_id;
    int i;

    sem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, sem_id);
    sem = OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS, 1, sem_id);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadFunction, NULL, 0, &thread_id); 
        if (hThread == NULL) {
            PERROR("CreateThread");
        }
    }
}
DWORD WINAPI threadFunction(LPVOID par){
    DWORD result;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        result = WaitForSingleObject(sem, INFINITE);
        switch (result) {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            PERROR("wait error");
            break;
        }
        if (ReleaseSemaphore(sem, 1, NULL) == 0) {
            PERROR("release error");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am doing something wrong but I don't know what. I open the semaphore before using it. I never close the semaphore.

edit:

I just removed the 2 OpenSemaphore lines and it works fine.

Comment: Looks like the handle was closed. I don't see how we can help wIthout a [mcve].

Comment: you should give some background about "sem". How your program/thread is using this. Otherwise it is hard to suggest for error. Error shows Handle is closed. May be you never open it or closed it in between.

Comment: @WernerHenze Thanks for your reply. I'll do it and upgrade the question.

Comment: @WernerHenze check the edit if you wish, i just put the minimal example

Comment: `CreateSemaphore` and then just `OpenSemaphore` ?! use global variables, not close handles, your main just exist after thread created..you not check any api call result, etc

Comment: hist - senseless call `OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS, 1, sem_id);` always fail and return 0 because `sem_id == 0`.

Comment: Hey @RbMm thanks for your reply :)
What should I do with sem_id then? I thought that way would work fine, I don't know. Notice that I'm just a student, I'm just getting in touch with programming. 
Try not to be rude next time, I just asked and I know that I have a lot to learn. Take care.

Comment: at first - you not need call `OpenSemaphore` - for what ?! ask yourself. at second you not need name for semaphore - name in general need only if you need use it from multiple processes. if api return not *void* - check it return value. etc